# Vlookup equivalent Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to create a foreach loop to go through all the objects in an array $UserNames (users who logged in to application) then Vlookup the value against a table $Permissions (Table displaying ALL users and their permissions level) Then display results in another table using $hash $Combined.

```
$Usernames

jseri4
strin4
liker3
...

$Permissions:

Username    Permission_Level
jeri4       4
strin4      5
liker3      7
kingr6      5
georg5      4
```

I want $Combined to look like this

```
Username    Permission Level
x           y
```

```
foreach($j in $Usernames)
{
    foreach($s in $Permissions)
    {
        if($j -match $s.Username)
        {

            $hash =@{
                Username = $j
                UserType = $s.Permission_Level
             }
        $Build = New-Object PSOBJECT -Property $hash
        $Total = $Total + 1
        $Combined += $Build
        }
    }
}
```

$Combined from this code is displaying hundreds of results and does not display anything for UserType in any row for hashtable.

```
Username   Usertype
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
y
y
y
y
...
```

Comment: You can definitely use a hashtable for this but in this case, it looks like you actually want to filter `$Permissions` where `Username` in `$Usernames`

Comment: You say `$j in $username` instead of `$j in $usernames`.  Adding to $combined gives an error.

Comment: @js2010 that was a typo putting it into this forum I will correct it

Comment: I assume you have `$combined = @()` somewhere.  With that in, it works for me.   `+=` is ineffecient though.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the `$Permissions` array into a hashtable with the Username value as the key, then you can use it as a lookup table:

```
# populate lookup table
$PermissionTable = @{}
$Permissions |ForEach-Object { $PermissionTable[$_.Username] = $_.Permission_Level }

# create new list of objects
$Combined = $Usernames |Select-Object @{Name='Username';Expression={$_}},@{Name='Permission Level';Expression={$PermissionTable[$_]}}
```

If you want the translated property to be named `Usertype`, change `@{Name='Permission Level'; ...}` to `@{Name='Usertype'; ...}`

Comment: Thank you.... How would I turn the $Permissions array into a hashtable? $PermissionTable[$_.Username] <--- Wouldn't this be null because $PermissionTable = @{} and has no values?

Comment: The `$_` refers to the individual items from `$Permissions` being processed one by one

Answer (score 0):

If the list of usernames isn't too long, you can simply filter `$permissions` using the [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#containment-operators) operator:

```sh
$permissions.Where{ $usernames -contains $_.Username }

# Alternatively:
$permissions | Where-Object { $usernames -contains $_.Username }
```

The larger the `$usernames` array is, the slower the filtering will be as the `-contains` operator *linearly* scans the `$usernames` array for each element of `$permissions`.

If this becomes a bottleneck, you may convert `$usernames` into a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0), which provides *constant-time* lookup:

```sh
# Convert usernames array to HashSet of strings
$usernamesSet = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]] $usernames

# Use the HashSet to efficiently lookup user names
$permissions.Where{ $usernamesSet.Contains( $_.Username ) }
```

Note that `HashSet` is *case-sensitive* by default. To make it case-insensitive, construct it with an appropriate `StringComparer`:

```sh
$usernamesSet = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new( $usernames, [StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase )
```